# is it possible to use one AdSense account with other YouTube account?

Tags: youtube, google-adsense

So, basically, it's little bit complicated situation, and I want to know if it can be done.

I'm using YouTube with `example1@gmail.com` and have two channels on YouTube.

I want to use a newly created email address which is `example2@gmail.com` for AdSense. So what I want is this:

Is it possible to connect a YouTube channel and to monetize videos, but in a way to create new AdSense account and connect both AdSense and YouTube, just with two different accounts, one for YouTube, and other for AdSense?

I've tried to do that, but Google keeps logging me out when I sign in with other account.

Comment: I accidentially clicked _Leave Open_ - this question should really be migrated to [webmasters.se].

Comment: I'm willing to put more bounty if someone can solve this.

Comment: You say "Google keeps logging me out when I sign in with other account." - when you log in to what?

Comment: I just posted what I've tried. I want to know how it's done with two separate accounts.

Comment: anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution, it was via mobile, but it's a solution.

AdSense
If you don't want to use the AdSense account currently connected to your Google Account, try one of the following:

- Sign in with a different Google Account connected to the AdSense
  account you'd like to use with AdMob.
- Remove yourself from the AdSense account and let AdMob create a new
  one for you when you sign up.
- Remove yourself from the AdSense account and add yourself to the
  correct account before signing up.
- Cancel and close the AdSense account. Canceling your account should
  be a last resort reserved for inactive accounts that aren't currently
  receiving ad requests or generating revenue. Please note that if you
  cancel the account you will lose access to the account data. If you
  don't see the option to cancel your account when you sign in to
  AdSense, please contact AdSense support.

As stated on [this](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6014439?hl=en) link.

Comment: if someone has another way, I'm willing to get this bounty to that solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that it is possible, and that I've done it.   Will check the details of how I did it later on when I have more time.

But your first challenge will be to get    example2@gmail.com   signed up as an AdSense publisher in it's own right.    There are certain rules about who can sign up, including that you have "something" to show ads on, which meets their programme rules.    You may need to set up a website to do this.  (as a very rough guide, at least 10 pages of unique content, with a privacy policy - there are more rules than that).

Getting the account signed up an an AdSense publisher is presumably not as challenging if you're using your regular YouTube account - because YouTube is your content.

Comment: I'm using one account for youtube and I want to activate adsense with another account.

Comment: I understand that.   But you will have to get AdSense set up for the 2nd account before you can use it on your YouTube account (or anywhere else).

Comment: yeah, it's all setted up.

Comment: So, are you going to give any details here?